# generate code in cakephp same like rails using scaffold generator

Tags: cakephp, scaffolding

How can create my model, controller and view files in cakephp same we do in rails using scaffold generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1103/Scaffolding